# Filter Mssql records based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have columns A,B,C in my sql result. Column B might have duplicate records. To avoid duplicate B values, I need to check value in C. If the column C has value 0 then only that particular row should be selected in B.

This treatment should be done only for duplicate records.

```
Column A | Column B | Column C

value 1  | value 2  | 1

value 3  | value 2  | 0
```

In the above code only row, value 3  | value 2  | 0 , should be selected in the query result

Comment: show a sample, please, text is not that clear...

Comment: OK. So, where is you code and effort? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    A, B, C
FROM
(
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY CASE WHEN C = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn,
    A, B, C
FROM Tbl
) A
WHERE rn = 1
```

If minimum value of `C` is 0 you can `ORDER BY` just by `C`.

Comment: you got ahead of me :), attaching fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f221/2)

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
SELECT  t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB, t1.ColumnC
FROM dbo.test32 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.test32 t2             
                  WHERE t2.ColumnB = t1.ColumnB
                  GROUP BY t2.ColumnB
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND MAX(t2.ColumnC) = t1.ColumnC
                  )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7660b/1/0)